# I am getting error when try send sms using laravel-smpp

Tags: php, laravel, smpp

This is error:socket_close(): Argument #1 ($socket) must be of type Socket, null given,
path:/vendor/php-smpp/php-smpp/sockettransport.class.php

Comment: try giving more in codes, its not clear how you got this error. you might not giving configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in php version, packet smpp don't work in version 8.0 i change to 7.4 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Go to the php ini file in xampp and enabled extention socket. Change:
`;extension=sockets` to `extension=sockets`.

Check this image:
[How to enabled socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BH1a.png)